# grep for word up until char

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep, gnu

I'm trying to grep two strings and the next word until a char from a file .
The current content looks something like this:

```
Package: wdiff\0aVersion: 1.2.2-1build1\0aArchitecture: amd64\0aMaintainer:...
...

Package: python\0aVersion: 2.7.2-1build1\0aArchitecture: amd64\0aMaintainer:..
...
```

and so on . 
I want to grep the file for the words "Package:" and "Versions" together up until `"\0a"`.
so that the output would be:

```
Package: wdiff Version: 1.2.2-1build1
Package: python Version: 2.7.2-1build1
```

and so on , preferably using grep.

Just to clarify - this is a long file with many words sepereted by "\0a" and I want only 2 words and the everything after them until "\0a".

Thanks for the kind help!

Comment: *until "\a0"* - and why `build1` is missed?

Comment: Is there literal `\0a` used in the input file?

Comment: Your example has `\0a`, but your text says `\a0` - which is it? Are these literal characters, or do you mean linefeeds?

Comment: Specify: Are you referring to a literal Nul character `\0` in escaped form or the series of two character back slash + ascii `0`?

Comment: Sorry , I meant until \0a and include the "build1" in the output so it would be Package: wdiff Version: 1.2.2-1build1 . \0a are literal chars , the appear in the output and I want to grep everything up until those chars . Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a single awk command to get the output:

```
awk -F '\\\\0a' 'NF>1{print $1, $2}' file

Package: wdiff Version: 1.2.2-1build1
Package: python Version: 2.7.2-1build1
```

`-F '\\\\0a'` sets `\0a` as input field separator.

Comment: That's awesome ,thanks! however , I do have some lines where I have another word in between package and version and it outputs it as well . for example: "Package: apache\0aSource: blabla\0aVersion: 3.2.1" and so on . How to I keep Source: out of the output?

Comment: ok then use: `awk -F '\\\\0a' 'NF>1{print $1, ($2 ~ /^Version:/ ? $2 : $3)}' file`

Comment: Yes , beautifully !! thanks a lot man . Up voted :) In case I want to add another pattern in the future , that would catch a 3rd word from the line , how do I add it ?

Comment: done;) I'll be happy if you could tell me how to add a 3rd pattern if that's not to much of a hassle

Comment: If it is closely related to this problem then tell me, (I will help) otherwise it is best to open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

One option is:

```
awk -F\\ '{ pos=match($2,"build");print $1" "substr($2,3,pos-3) }'
```

We split the text using awk and the separator "\" We want to strip the second element further from the 3rd character to the word "build" So we use the match function in awk to find where is in the string and then further take the second string from the 3rd character up to where ever the word "build" appears (minus 3 to take account of the "0a" at the start of the string.

Answer (score -1):

> to grep the file for the words "Package:" and "Versions" together up
>   until "\a0"

***grep*** allows you to find matches but it won't replace the "unneeded" characters.
Use combination of ***grep*** + ***sed***:

```
cat testfile | grep -Po 'Package: .+?Version: .+?(?=\\0a)' | sed 's/\(.*\)\\0a.*\(Version.*\)/\1 \2/'
```

The exemplary output:

```
Package: wdiff Version: 1.2.2-1build1
Package: python Version: 2.7.2-1build1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! I think you may have miss understood me . Lets assume that it's a very long file ,not separated by lines and I want to grep the words "Package:" and everything after it until the chars "\0a" and also "Version: " and everything after it until the chars "\0a" . There are also other words in the lines such as "Maintainer:" , "Architecture:" and so on .

Comment: @JohnDoe, you should have mentioned that there is an arbitrary text , not lines with linebreaks

Comment: thanks it works great! however , I do have some lines where I have another word in between package and version and it outputs it as well . for example: "Package: apache\0aSource: blabla\0aVersion: 3.2.1" and so on . How to I keep Source: out of the output?

Comment: I tried up voting you if that helps :) but I'd appreciate it if you could help out from the bottom of my heart .